# passing parameters in query function in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm a beginner in Jquery and I cannot find out the solution to my problem.

In cakephp,  I have a view where I call my jquery script in the following way:

```
<?php echo $this->Js->click; ?>
```

the jquery function is the following

```
$(function ()
    {
      $('#toogle-data').hover(function ()
      {
      $(this).toggleClass('Highlight');
      });


      $('#toggle-data').click(function ()
      {
        $("#more").hide();

        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("normal");
      });


     });
```

This works fine.

But when I want to pass parameter, it does not work

in the view I replace the above call by

```
<?php echo $this->Js->click('#toggle-data'); ?>
```

and I change the first line of my jquery funnction as the following

```
$(function (x)
```

I got the following message

```
JsHelper:: Missing Method click is undefined [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\JsHelper.php
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: i guess ur understanding of how jquery and js works in wrong..share wht u are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

### click isn't a method

If you want to use [the Js helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#javascript-engine-usage), then probably you'll need syntax similar to:

```
$this->Js->get('#toogle-data')->event('click', $eventCode);
```

Though, from the code in the question you don't need this helper at all - it's for generating appropriate event handlers which are already present in the javascript code.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Let's say that I want to call my own function  "my_function" instead of click,  what should I do ?

Comment: Don't really know what you mean - call it when? You are best off simply ignoring the js helper imo, js logic belongs in a js file.

Comment: My aim was to use my jquery function in any view. For that, I need, inside the view to pass the parameter (the Id) of the block that I want my jquery function to run for.

Answer (score 0):

@AD7six is correct in that `click` is not a method of JsHelper.

What you're trying to achieve would be best done by [creating your own helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers).

With your own helper you could create a method that returns the click function.

Comment: My aim was to use my jquery function in any view. For that, I need, inside the view to pass the parameter (the Id) of the block that I want my jquery function to run for.

Comment: Read through the link; with helpers you can do exactly what you need.