# jquery and cakephp - how to pass parameter in my jquery function

Tags: jquery, cakephp

sorry for posting a similar post of my previous one but I think that my explanation was not good.

Actually, I have a jquery function that I use in a cakephp view

This works for a given view.

I would like to be able to use this jquery function with other views by passing parameter (the id of the div that I want the jquery function to run for.

My question is ,  which changes do I need to do in my function to make it works, and how to call it from my view  (syntax please).

I hope that experts of this site will help, I cannot find out in documentation.

Here is my jquery function

```
$(function 
    {
      // Hide the first cell for JavaScript enabled browsers.
      //$('#link-data td:first-child').hide();   

      $('#moreWrapper ').hover(function ()
      {
        $(this).toggleClass('Highlight');
      });

      // run after page loads       
      $("#more").hide();


      // Assign a click handler that grabs the URL 
      // from the first cell and redirects the user.
      $('#moreWrapper ').click(function ()
      {

        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(100);
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor

      });


     });
```

Comment: Unless there's something significantly different - Please just edit your existing question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing parameters in query function in cakephp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578971/passing-parameters-in-query-function-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your controller action give the name of the div to the view:

```
$this->set('div', 'moreWrapper');
```

that way you will have the $div variable available in your view wich holds: 'moreWrapper' in this case and then just echo it out into your jQuery selectors:

so you just replace Replace `#moreWrapper` with `#<?php echo $div ?>`

```
$('#<?php echo $div ?>').hover(function ()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('Highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your controller's action:

```
$this->set('domElement', 'moreWrapper_or_some_other_name');
```

In the corresponding view file, use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

<?php if(!empty($domElement)) {?>

    // Hide the first cell for JavaScript enabled browsers.
    //$('#link-data td:first-child').hide();
    $('#<?php echo $domElement;?>').hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('Highlight');
    });

    // run after page loads
    $("#more").hide();

    // Assign a click handler that grabs the URL 
    // from the first cell and redirects the user.
    $('#<?php echo $domElement;?>').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(100);
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });

<?php }?>

    //other javascript code implementation here......
});
</script>
```